# Use of popup windows when the destination cookie is HTTPOnly

Tags: javascript, httponly

I have a Javascript script that opens a popup window passing a JWT token to a page.

This page uses the JWT token and creates a session, storing its ID in a cookie.

Once this is done, I am authenticated on the page.

It turns out that if I click again on the script that opens the popup, the JWT is passed again and the last cookie is "forgotten", it does not detect the previous session and redoes the entire authentication.

Is there any way for the previous cookie to remain?
Is this caused by the cookie being HTTPOnly?

Comment: One simple solution, is disable the ability to click to open the window.

Comment: "*it does not detect the previous session*" This seems like the crux of the issue, is your server side code doing a check for the cookie (& its validity) before rerunning the authentication? Is there any reason to allow the session to get blown away if the cookie is present with a valid session ID?

Comment: @esqew If I run the URL opened by the popup, directly in the browser and always re-execute it directly through the browser, this problem does not occur.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not related to HttpOnly, which only blocks access from JavaScript (hides it from the `document.cookie` property).

There is not enough information to solve it, but here are some ideas.

- Are the original page and the popup on the same domain (origin)? If not, maybe it could be related to the [SameSite attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#:%7E:text=/fr/docs-,SameSite%20attribute,-The%20SameSite%20attribute).
- Are you sure the session cookie is not sent to the second popup? Can you check HTTP logs? (If you can't see it in Developer Tools because they open too late, either log it server side, or try using `chrome://net-export/`.)
- Maybe the session cookie is sent, but the popup page doesn't check or read the cookie, it just unconditionally creates a new session.
- Does it also happen when it's a normal page load instead of a popup?

---

To prove HttpOnly is not the problem, here is a tiny demo node.js server in which the popup can tell if you already have a cookie or not.

```js
const http = require("http");

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.url == "/") {
    res.writeHead(200, { "content-type": "text/html" });
    res.end(`
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <p>
      <button id="openpopup" type="button">Open a popup</button>
      <p>
      <button id="sendother" type="button">Send normal request</button>
      <p>
      <button id="showcookie" type="button">Show document.cookie</button>
      <scr`+`ipt>
      function log(msg) {
        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.append(String(msg));
        document.body.append(div);
      }
      document.getElementById('openpopup').onclick = () => {
        window.open('/popup?jwt=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({ "jwt_foo": "jwt_bar" })), '', 'width=500,height=500');
      };
      document.getElementById('sendother').onclick = () => {
        fetch('/normalrequest').then(r => r.json()).then(r => log(JSON.stringify(r)));
      };
      document.getElementById('showcookie').onclick = () => {
        log("document.cookie is: " + document.cookie);
      };
      window.onmessage = (event) => {
        log("Received message from popup: " + event.data);
      }
      </scr`+`ipt>
    `);
    return;
  }

  if (req.url.startsWith("/popup")) {
    if (req.headers.cookie && req.headers.cookie.match(/sessioncookie/)) {
      res.writeHead(200, { "content-type": "text/html" });
      res.end(`
        <p>You're already logged in! No cookie for you!
        <scr`+`ipt>window.opener.postMessage("No cookie for you");</scr`+`ipt>
      `);
    } else {
      const sessionid = String(Math.random());
      res.writeHead(200, { "content-type": "text/html", "set-cookie": "sessioncookie=" + sessionid + "; HttpOnly" });
      res.end(`
        <p>Thanks for the token! Your new session id is ${sessionid}.
        <scr`+`ipt>window.opener.postMessage("Received new session id");</scr`+`ipt>
      `);
    }
    return;
  }

  if (req.url == "/normalrequest") {
    const response = req.headers.cookie && req.headers.cookie.match(/sessioncookie/)
      ? { "status": "ok", "value": "You are logged in! Cookies: " + req.headers.cookie }
      : { "status": "error", "value": "Authentication required!" };
    res.writeHead(200, { "content-type": "application/json" });
    res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
    return;
  }

  res.writeHead(404, { "content-type": "text/html" });
  res.end("404 not found");
});

server.listen(5077);
```

Comment: The loaded popup and the page that has the script to open the popup are different domains.

There is also the sameSite property enabled for the popup domain.

Comment: Then that's probably the issue. Try setting it to `SameSite=Lax`. That's the best value. If that doesn't work, try removing SameSite or setting it to `SameSite=None`.